# Flutter ListView won't Update

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, sqflite

I am new to Flutter development. I just started to make Note app with Provider pattern, but when I update note, It won't update and It just create a new note in list. But when I minimize and return back list is updated. when I click on the item, it shows old data. Help me

**sqlite_helper.dart**

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';

class DBHelper {
  static Future<Database> database() async {
    final dbPath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
    return sql.openDatabase(path.join(dbPath, 'mydatabase.db'),
        onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE notes(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, content TEXT)');
    }, version: 1);
  }

  static Future<void> insert(String table, Map<String, Object> data) async {
    final db = await DBHelper.database();
    db.insert(
      table,
      data,
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you haven't wrote any update query yet

Comment: I think conflictAlgorithm will replace it with new content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NoteProvider doesn't have update logic, here `_items.add(newNote)` will add an item at the end. So the existing list item not going to get updated.

Below will be an example of how to list items can be updated, you can still around this there are a lot of answers available.

```
_items[_items.indexWhere((note) => note.id == newNote.id)] = newNote;
```

Comment: ya. that works, conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace, then why this not replacing the note?

Comment: That is for database not for Provider class, Provider locals variables should be updated as well. Could you upvote and accept the answer?